# mysqli_query(): Empty query, error in selecting, how to solve it?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='queries.php'>
       <label>name1</label>
       <input type='checkbox' name='name1'/>
       <label>name2</label>
       <input type='checkbox' name='name2'/>
       <label>name3</label>
       <input type='checkbox' name='name3'/>
       <input type='submit' name='sendData' value='Send'/>
      </form>";
```

What i'm trying to do is to perform a dynamic query after submitting the form above.

```
  $formData = isset($_POST) ? $_POST : 0; 
    $data = array_keys($formData);
    array_pop($data);
    
    $sendData = isset( $_POST['sendData']);

    $infoIn= ".infoIn";
    $resQuery = '';
    $unionAll = "UNION ALL";

    switch ($sendData) { 

        case 'loadData':

          for ($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {

            $schemaTab = $data[$i] . $infoIn;
            $query = "(SELECT '$data[$i]' as 'Schema', MIN(concat(DATEIN, ' ', HOURIN)) as DATEHOUR, COUNT(*) as counting FROM $schemaTab WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1)" . $unionAll;
            $resQuery .= $query;      
  
          }       
                                
          $resFinalQuery = substr($resQuery, 0 ,-9);
         
          $total = "SELECT SUM(counting) FROM($resFinalQuery)cnt";
  
          $resQuery=$db->getQuery($resFinalQuery);
          $resTot=$db->getQuery($total);
          
          $res[] = $resQuery;
          $res[] = $resTot;
          
          echo json_encode($res);

        break;

        case 'noData':

          echo "<p>No data Passed</p>";
                
        break;
```

The problem happens when nothing is selected, saying the problem is in the variable $resFinalQuery and $total because they start as empty. How can i solve this?

Comment: I wonder if you ever get any results from this. `$sendData = isset( $_POST['$sendData']);` makes no sense; I assume you meant `$_POST['sendData']` (without the inner dollar sign). Next up, you try to compare your `$sendData` variable to some strings, but you assign it only the boolean value that `isset` returns.

Comment: @El_Vanja that was a translating error. Forgot to delete it while translating the cod ein english.

Comment: Ok, but that still doesn't change the fact that you're trying to compare a boolean to strings. `$sendData` never has the value of `'loadData'` or `'noData'`, only `true`. Because of that, it will always match the first case, since any non-empty string matches `true`.

Comment: @El_Vanja ok i got it now what you are saying Thanks. I need to rethink the code. How would you suggest me to proceed?

Comment: It also makes no sense to call `array_keys` on `$formData` when it's `0`. Your logic is all over the place at the moment. First off, `isset($_POST['sendData'])` should be your main condition. Inside that, you should do whatever you want to do when the form is submitted. In the else branch of that condition, do whatever you need when it's not. Currently you have some unnecessary complications that require a ton of checks before you use your variables.

Comment: @El_Vanja Ok got it thanks. Going to recode.